# ble web cannot read from a characteristic

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I built up a bee peripheral module using blend on the raspberry pi that sends a list of wifi network. The snippet for the read characteristics :

```
class ResultCharacteristic extends bleno.Characteristic {
constructor() {
    super({
        uuid: RESULT_UUID,
        properties: ["read"],
        value: null,
        descriptors: [
            new bleno.Descriptor({
                uuid: ARGUMENT_1_UUID,
                value: "Calculation result"
              })
        ]
    });


}

onReadRequest(offset, callback) {
    try {

        const result = scannedNetworks.join();
    console.log(result);
        console.log(`Returning result: ${result}`);

        let data = new Buffer(result);

        callback(this.RESULT_SUCCESS, data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        callback(this.RESULT_UNLIKELY_ERROR);
    }
}
```

}

Now I check for the data received on my iPhone using LightBlue and I see a list of wifi ssids.

When I read the characteristics from ble web, I get a "NotSupportedError: GATT operation failed for unknown reason."

here is the part to read that characteristics.

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(options)
  .then(device => {
    console.log('> Name:             ' + device.name);
    console.log('> Id:               ' + device.id);
    console.log('> Connected:        ' + device.gatt.connected);
    return device.gatt.connect();
  })
  .then(server => {

    return server.getPrimaryService(tem);
  })
  .then(service => {
    // console.log('services');
    // console.log(service);
    return service.getCharacteristic('00010010-89bd-43c8-9231-40f6e305f96d');
  })
  .then(characteristic => {
    listn = characteristic;
    // console.log(characteristic);
    // listn.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', (e) => {
    //   console.log('fired');
    //   console.log(decoder.decode(e.target.value));
    // });
    // console.log(characteristic);
    // return characteristic.getDescriptors();
    return characteristic.readValue();
  })
  // .then(descriptors => {
  //   // return descriptors.readValue();
  //   console.log(descriptors);
  // })
  .then(value => {
    // let decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
    console.log(value);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Argh! ' + error);
  });
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sure your browser is compatible ? https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md Safari doesn't handle BLE

Comment: safari is so broken that it lists out the ble devices but doesn't let me connect to any?

Comment: Doenst seems to work on safari. I tested for you in my solution : it works well on Google chrome(v65.0.3325.181) but as soon I request the bluetooth object in Safari (v11.0), I got the console log : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice). So it won't let you handle any bluetooth functionalities.